# user activation email doesn't work

Tags: user-registration, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a question about the Gravity forms Plugin  ... I'm going to create a registration form
And for that, I used the description of the link below.

https://gravitywiz.com/customizing-the-user-activation-email-for-gravity-forms/

But the problem is that no email is sent to the registered user, so that they can complete the signup submission link.
I do not understand where the problem is?

Comment: Can you please first confirm whether email is working in your system or not? You can use plugin like this to check. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-test-email/ Disclaimer: I am not related to the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found answer
If you also encountered this problem, you can use "wp smtp config" plugins 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp-config/